# Profile pictures in react dates calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, calendar, react-dates

[image]

Hi all

Can I have image in particular days in react-dates calendar as in attached picture?

Answer (score 1):

use the the method `renderDayContents` which is provided by react dates and render your custom dates.

For more info check reac-dates docs: https://airbnb.io/react-dates/?path=/story/sdp-day-props--with-custom-daily-details